# In Mongoose Return only documents where parent value is matched and subdocument result is true

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

In MongoDb I currently have documents that resemble the below one shown. I have multiple documents like the one below. For example, I would like to pull back only the image paths that contain at least 25 percent of hex value BA4D2A and 75 percent of FFAB23.

```
{
    "__v": 0,
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "51c1ac95f502f20969000022"
    },
    "hex": "BA4D2A",
    "img": [
        {
            "path": "http://example.com/image1.jpg",
            "perc": 10,
            "_id": {
                "$oid": "51c1ac95f502f20969000023"
            }
        },
        {
            "path": "http://example.com/image2.jpg",
            "perc": 20,
            "_id": {
                "$oid": "51c1ac95f502f20969000034"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

After kindly getting help from a previous question, I have the below query that works awesome for pulling back the paths if I was looking for all hex values having over a single specified percentage amount, but I realized that I would like to be able to handle each percentage seperately for each hex value.

If you couldn't tell I am about 4 days into playing with Mongoose/MongoDb, so if there is a better way of doing this (architecture wise) I am open to ideas.  This approach is just something I came up with from reading the docs and google.

```
clrModel.find({
            hex: {$in: [ "5B6D8B", "BA4D2A" ] } ,
            'img.perc': {$gte: 5}
            } ,
            'img.path', 
            function(error,data){
              //Handle my data res accordingly  
            });
};
```

EDIT -----------
I have managed to get something a little closer to what I want with the below code block but I want only the paths that meet all the criteria. The below query returns back all the results for each individual hex query, but I am wanting the paths for only the images that contain both hex values and their percentages if that makes sense.

```
clrModel.find({ 
            $or: [
                {hex: "5B6D8B", 'img.perc':{$gte: 5}}, 
                {hex: "BA4D2A", 'img.perc':{$gte: 12}}
                ],
        } , 
        'img.path', 
        function(error,data){   });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think issue is the way you are structuring your entries. There is only one hex field per document, which means that it is impossible for a document to contain both values. To query what you want, each path name needs to have an associated array of hex values and percentages, so you could then execute an $and query that works.

Comment: I did it this way because I was wanting to pull back all images that contained that hex color value.  So in the document, it contains the hex value and then all images that contain that color as well as their percentage of that color.  I did this so I would not have to look through every single index in the db and check to see if it contained the hex values.  When I wanted to pull back images with 2 hex color values, I only index those specific indicies and retrieve all those image paths, filtering back based on percentages.  Is this a bad approach?

Comment: I am going to put yours as the answer as I think I need to just re-look at my arch.  Thanks!

Comment: Yeah i don't think mongo supports queries between documents like that, either pull all the images back and do the logic yourself (if its not too big a request), or restructure the db to be image by image.